# How to wrap every test in mochajs with setup+teardown or before+after functions?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I have a lot of tests, that require to create same object, do similar operation, check for emitted events, destroy object.

Is it possible not to write in every mocha test code for creating and destroying object instance?

```
describe('Instance to be tested', function() {

  var instance;

  before(function (next) {
    // is called before every test (not testsuite)
    var instance = new ...
    next();
  });

  after(function(){
    // is called after every test (not testsuite)
    instance.shutdown();
  });

  describe('event 1', function () {
    it('emits event 1', function (done) {
      assert(true);
      done();
    });
  });

  describe('event 2 ', function () {
    it('emits event 2 ', function (done) {
      assert(true);
      done();
    });
  });

  describe('event 3 ', function () {
    it('emits event 3 ', function (done) {
      assert(true);
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Are you looking for `beforeEach`/`afterEach`?

Comment: @AaronDufour hm.. just successfully ran `setup` and `teardown` functions with tdd for every test. `beforeEach` and `afterEach` are same for bdd?

Comment: Yes, i was actually looking for them. Thanks a lot!